# Can't refresh chromium from snap

Tags: snap, chromium, process

I have a kiosk-like device that uses chromium, and I am configuring it remotely. I need to update chromium from snap. `sudo snap refresh --list` shows me an available update, but if I try to `sudo snap refresh chromium`, I get

```
error: cannot refresh "chromium": snap "chromium" has running apps (chromedriver, chromium), pids:
       14128,14130,14288,14290,14294,...
```

When I try `sudo kill -9 14128 14130 14288 14290 14294 ... ; sudo snap refresh chromium`, it is sometimes able to download chromium but when it tries to install, it results in this:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Make current revision for snap "chromium" unavailable (snap "chromium" has running apps (chromedriver, chromium), pids: 15010,15014,15173,15176,...
```

New pids are immediately spawned as soon as I kill them all.

Is there a way to tell snap to FORCE a refresh?

inb4 "don't use snap": this is the current approach my team is taking. If I am truly blocked I will switch, but I'm certain there must be a solution to this.